# React Code Splitting - Stopping low level components from downloading on initial load

Tags: reactjs, code-splitting

I have my components structured to distinguish between top level Page components and then other lower level components. In my index.js I am lazy loading all my Page components, but the benefit is negligible due to all my lower level components still being downloaded up front. This is presumably due to them all being exposed via an index.js file at the root of my component tree.

```
    //index.js
    export {
       // multiple components here
    } from './application';

    export {
       // multiple components here
    } from './shared';
```

I do this so that I can import any component with a simple `import { une, dues, trois } from 'components'`, but it means that ALL components are served up front as a result.

I don't really want to have to individually lazy load every single component in all my component imports, so is there a simpler way to be able to ensure that a component is only downloaded when it is explicitly required by a lazy loaded parent component or is there a way to set my index.js so it supports code splitting without explicitly lazy loading each one?

Answer (score 0):

So I read this article https://medium.com/@alonmiz1234/why-you-should-avoid-index-js-3321a9902120 and decided that having greater control over when components would be downloaded outweighed the conveniences of exposing all your exports via root index.js files. So I updated all my local application imports to import directly from the component and removed my index.js files. Code splitting now behaves as expected, with my top level page components being lazy loaded and all their dependent lower level components only being downloaded to the browser when required.